# How to link Spark output to Logstash input

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs, logstash, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming job outputting some logs which are currently stored in HDFS, and I want to process them with logstash. Unfortunately it seems that although there is a plugin to write in hdfs for logstash, it is imposible to actually **read** from hdfs with it.

I have search a solution to link the two parts but in so far as in Spark streaming for python api, the only way to store something is to write it in hdfs as a text file, so I have to read from hdfs ! 
I cannot save them locally because Spark runs on a cluster, and I don't want to fetch all the data from each node.

Currently I run an extremely dirty script that copies the content the hdfs directory localy each 2 seconds. But this solution is clearly not satisfying.

Does anybody know a software that could help me to send the output of Spark to Logstash ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :** I use Python & Spark 1.6.0

Comment: Are these the logs generated by Log4j?

Comment: Nope, this are apache logs processed by Spark which adds some feature to it based on machine learning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect job to use [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) for. In your Spark Streaming job, write to Kafka, then consume the record from Logstash.

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
    val producer = createKafkaProducer()
    partition.foreach { message =>
      val record = ... // convert message to record
      producer.send(record)
    }
    producer.close()
  }
}
```